# Explaining formulas for $A$, $B$, $C$ in the equation $Ax+By+C$ of the line through two given points

Tags: geometry

In a computer program, I can make a line equation $Ax + By + C$ from two points like:

$$\begin{align}
A &= y_2-y_1 \\
B &= x_1-x_2 \\
C &= A\cdot x_1+B\cdot y_1
\end{align}$$

[Source on TopCoder.com](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/geometry-concepts-line-intersection-and-its-applications/)

I do not understand how $A$, $B$, $C$ values arise from the points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line 
goes through the points
$(x_1, y_1)$
and
$(x_2, y_2)$,
then a point
$(x, y)$
is on the line
if and only if
$\frac{x-x_1}{y-y_1}
=\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}
$
or
$x(y_2-y_1)-x_1(y_2-y_1)
=y(x_2-x_1)-y_1(x_2-x_1)
$
or
$x(y_2-y_1)-y(x_2-x_1)
=x_1(y_2-y_1)-y_1(x_2-x_1)
$
which is your equation.

Comment: Some care must be taken since the line may be horizontal, in which case $\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}$ is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I get this. But I don't understand (x−x1)(y−y1)=(x2−x1)(y2−y1). 
Sorry I dont know Latex.

Comment: This is the two-point form of a straight line. It says that, if the slope of a line is $r$, then, for any two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ on the line, $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1) = r$.

Comment: @martychhen - Can you please explain the "if and only if" part - how did you get that equation?